# How to retrieve metadata from photo's using Dropzone and Javascript

Tags: javascript, upload, metadata, photo, multer

I am using Dropzone to upload files to my Node server and I am using Multer.

I have been doing some looking around and find very little information, really none, about how to retrieve metadata from photo's. I would like to gather the date the photo was taken/created, if it's uploaded from mobile I'm sure there are GPS tags these days and that could be helpful.

Is there any good documentation or has anyone done anything like this? I just can't find anything, Dropzone has nothing on metadata in their docs, just originalName.

If I am missing something simple, like how to console.log all of the photo metadata that would be great because I can see the metadata options.